# Фразеологизм "буриданов осел" как пишется?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Чаще сочетание пишется со строчной буквы, но иногда пишут и с прописной. Это зависит от текста? И какое там действует **правило?**

Текст такой: *В какой-то момент я и вовсе впаду в прострацию, как **Буриданов осел**. Глядя на эти земли, я бесконечно томилась сомнениями: что считать благом, что напастью, что назвать злом, что добром? Этому выдумщику Жану Буридану было проще.*

И кстати, можно ли как-то **спасти** осла?

Из Нацкорпуса:

― Куда тебе понять! ― саркастически воскликнул этот Буриданов осел. ― Твое счастье, что ты об этом даже не задумываешься.  [Илья Бояшов. Путь Мури (2007)]

А что пойдет? Вот и топчешься, как Буриданов осел, уже неделю в середине третьей главы... [Гоар Маркосян-Каспер. Кариатиды // «Звезда», 2003

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104354/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-----).

Answer (score 3):

В [НКРЯ](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2&startyear=1983&lex2=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=2003&mode=main&parent1=0&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&p=0) действительно *буриданов осел* наличествует и с прописной буквы, и в кавычках, и **со строчной буквы**. Я бы выбрала последний вариант, основываясь на правиле из [ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5821)
(" Собственные имена людей, животных, мифологических существ и производные от них слова"):

> ...в составе фразеологических оборотов и в составных терминах прилагательные с *-ов (-ев), -ин* пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: *ариаднина нить, ахиллесова пята, каинова печать, прокрустово ложе, сизифов труд, гордиев узел, демьянова уха, тришкин кафтан, филькина грамота*...

Comment: Спасибо, Римма,  почему-то мне нравится запись с прописной буквы. Именно в моем тексте.

Comment: Нравится, потому что хочется передать уникальность этого осла.

Answer (score 1):

Правило:

**Примечание 1. Прилагательные, образованные от индивидуальных названий людей, пишутся со строчной буквы**.

Ещё способ разрешить сомнение: свериться по орфографическому словарю Лопатина "Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой?"

Насчёт спасения осла я не понял. Как вариант: одну из кучек сена положить чуть ближе.

Comment: Спасибо, сверилась. Но мне кажется, что от текста тоже зависит. Индивидуальное название Буридан там тоже присутствует. А ближе сено класть нельзя, все должно быть одинаковым.